# Angular, Webpack5 Module Federation : You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected

Tags: angular, rxjs, webpack-5, webpack-module-federation

I am currently developing a project respecting a microfrontend architecture using Webpack5 Module Federation and Angular. I am dealing with a somewhat anondin problem. Indeed, all my microfrontends (remote) work perfectly alone but when integrating them into the shell (host). I have an error that appears and shows some bugs on the application.

```
ERROR TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected.  
You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
```

This error comes from Angular Core and especially when there is an integrated Angular Material component.

The craziest thing about this problem is that it’s no longer there when I activate the chrome extension "Redux Dev Tools".
Do you have any ideas ?

There’s probably a problem with sharing libraries, but I don’t know where?

My various configs of the host and remotes.

Shell:

```
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      remotes: {
          // all remotes that will be used in the shell
          'designer': "designer@http://localhost:4201/remoteEntry.js",
          'library':"library@http://localhost:4202/remoteEntry.js"
        },
      shared:  {
        // all libraries that will be shared with microfrontends
        "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        "@angular/forms":{ singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        "@angular/cdk":{ singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        "@angular/material":{ singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        //"@ngx-translate/core":{ singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        "@bl/auth-token": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        //"@bl/elements": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        "@bl/theme": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        "@bl/shared": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        "@bl/bl-app-layout": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
      }
  })
```

Remote 1 :

```
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
          
      // For remotes (please adjust)
      name: "library",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        './web-components': './src/bootstrap.ts',
      },        

      shared:  {
        "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        "@angular/forms":{ singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        "@angular/cdk":{ singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        "@angular/material":{ singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        //"@ngx-translate/core":{ singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        "@bl/auth-token": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        //"@bl/elements": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        "@bl/theme": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        "@bl/shared": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        "@bl/bl-app-layout": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
      }
    }),
```

Remote 2:

```
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
          
      // For remotes (please adjust)
      name: "designer",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        './web-components': './src/bootstrap.ts',
      },        

      shared:  {
        "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        "@angular/forms":{ singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        "@angular/cdk":{ singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        "@angular/material":{ singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        //"@ngx-translate/core":{ singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        "@bl/auth-token": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        //"@bl/elements": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        "@bl/theme": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        "@bl/shared": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
        "@bl/bl-app-layout": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
      }
    }),
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem as you. For me adding rxjs and rxjs/operators to the shared libraries in the ModuleFederationPlugin fixed the problem. I added the following libraries for both the shell and remote applications:

```js
'rxjs': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
'rxjs/operators': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: '~6.6.0' }
```

It is necessary to explicitly share rxjs/operators and also give a fixed version number to use as in the example.

Comment: What happens if different mfes use different rcxjs versions?